# part two of stringparsing.bat problems

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

Ok so everything's working with my **stringparsing.bat** program, i can successfully create, encode, and display the text files. However now the problem arises that it will not decode the the text file after encoding it. Say if the encoded text file contains:

`20 18 1 9 14 19`

When i decode it using this script:

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        Decoding Your Language File... Please Wait... 
echo.
echo.
echo.

for /f "delims=" %%i in (!name1!.txt) do ( 
set var1=%%i 
set var1=!var1:1 =a ! 
set var1=!var1:2 =b ! 
set var1=!var1:3 =c ! 
set var1=!var1:4 =d ! 
set var1=!var1:5 =e ! 
set var1=!var1:6 =f ! 
set var1=!var1:7 =g ! 
set var1=!var1:8 =h ! 
set var1=!var1:9 =i ! 
set var1=!var1:10 =j ! 
set var1=!var1:11 =k ! 
set var1=!var1:12 =l ! 
set var1=!var1:13 =m ! 
set var1=!var1:14 =n ! 
set var1=!var1:15 =o ! 
set var1=!var1:16 =p ! 
set var1=!var1:17 =q ! 
set var1=!var1:18 =r ! 
set var1=!var1:19 =s ! 
set var1=!var1:20 =t ! 
set var1=!var1:21 =u ! 
set var1=!var1:22 =v ! 
set var1=!var1:23 =w ! 
set var1=!var1:24 =x ! 
set var1=!var1:25 =y ! 
set var1=!var:26 =z !
set var1=!var1:27 =. !
set var1=!var1:28 =, ! 
echo        Verifying Content...

) 

echo %var1% > %name1%.txt
echo Decoding Complete!

TIMEOUT /t 1 /nobreak > nul
```

I get:

```
t 1h a i 1d 1i
```

Because when the program decodes the letter **r** (which is 18) it mistakes the 8 in 18 for the letter h and therefore puts **1h**... so is there a way to make it a specific search and replace? (similar to if your typing a path to a file with spaces in it,you would put quotes around the path and file name) If so what would the format be?

**EDIT** Heres the current script for the **stringparsing.bat** program:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
title BETA
cls
cd /d F:\script\st
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo      Setting Variables...
echo      Loading Language Database...

set beepset=true

:: ###################################################################################
::    CALLING VARIABLE DATABASE CALLING VARIABLE DATABASE CALLING VARIABLE DATABASE
:: ###################################################################################




TIMEOUT /t 5 /nobreak > nul

goto MAIN

:MAIN
cls
IF %beepset%==true echo 
echo =================================================================================
echo.
echo          Please type a name for your new language file:

echo =================================================================================
set /p name=
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ==============================================================
echo        ##############################################################
echo        #============================================================#
echo        #                                                            #
echo        # - Create the file you would like to encode.                #
echo        #                                                            #
echo        ##############################################################
echo        #                                                            #
echo        # - How many lines of text will your file have?              #
echo        #                                                            #
echo        #============================================================#
echo        ##############################################################
echo        ==============================================================




set /p linecount= 
cls
set foo=0
set linenumber=0

:lineset
set /a linenumber=linenumber+=1
set /p line1=%linenumber%
echo. >> %name%.txt
echo %line1% >> %name%.txt
set /a foo=foo+1
IF %foo%==%linecount% goto MAIN123
goto lineset


:ENCODE
title Step 2
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.      =================================================================================
echo.
echo          Please type a name of the File you want to Encode:
echo.
echo.         =================================================================================
set /p name2=

echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        Encoding Your Language File... Please Wait... 
echo.
echo.
echo.

for /f "delims=" %%i in (!name2!.txt) do ( 
set var=%%i 
set var=!var:a=1 ! 
set var=!var:b=2 ! 
set var=!var:c=3 ! 
set var=!var:d=4 ! 
set var=!var:e=5 ! 
set var=!var:f=6 ! 
set var=!var:g=7 ! 
set var=!var:h=8 ! 
set var=!var:i=9 ! 
set var=!var:j=10 ! 
set var=!var:k=11 ! 
set var=!var:l=12 ! 
set var=!var:m=13 ! 
set var=!var:n=14 ! 
set var=!var:o=15 ! 
set var=!var:p=16 ! 
set var=!var:q=17 ! 
set var=!var:r=18 ! 
set var=!var:s=19 ! 
set var=!var:t=20 ! 
set var=!var:u=21 ! 
set var=!var:v=22 ! 
set var=!var:w=23 ! 
set var=!var:x=24 ! 
set var=!var:y=25 ! 
set var=!var:z=26 ! 
set var=!var:.=27 !
echo        Verifying Content...

) 

echo %var% > %name2%.txt
echo Encoding Complete!

TIMEOUT /t 1 /nobreak > nul

goto MAIN123

:DECODE
title Decode...
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo         =================================================================================
echo.
echo          Please type a name of the File you want to decode:
echo.
echo         =================================================================================
set /p name1=

:decoderscript
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        Decoding Your Language File... Please Wait... 
echo.
echo.
echo.

for /f "delims=" %%i in (!name1!.txt) do ( 
set var1=%%i 
set var1=!var1:1 =a ! 
set var1=!var1:2 =b ! 
set var1=!var1:3 =c ! 
set var1=!var1:4 =d ! 
set var1=!var1:5 =e ! 
set var1=!var1:6 =f ! 
set var1=!var1:7 =g ! 
set var1=!var1:8 =h ! 
set var1=!var1:9 =i ! 
set var1=!var1:10 =j ! 
set var1=!var1:11 =k ! 
set var1=!var1:12 =l ! 
set var1=!var1:13 =m ! 
set var1=!var1:14 =n ! 
set var1=!var1:15 =o ! 
set var1=!var1:16 =p ! 
set var1=!var1:17 =q ! 
set var1=!var1:18 =r ! 
set var1=!var1:19 =s ! 
set var1=!var1:20 =t ! 
set var1=!var1:21 =u ! 
set var1=!var1:22 =v ! 
set var1=!var1:23 =w ! 
set var1=!var1:24 =x ! 
set var1=!var1:25 =y ! 
set var1=!var:26 =z !
set var1=!var1:27 =. !
set var1=!var1:28 =, ! 
echo        Verifying Content...

) 

echo %var1% > %name1%.txt
echo Decoding Complete!

TIMEOUT /t 1 /nobreak > nul

goto MAIN123


:DISPLAY
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        Please type the name of the file you want to display:
set /p displayfile= 
type %displayfile%.txt
echo.
echo hit enter to go to Main Menu...
pause > nul
goto MAIN123

:END
cls
title SHUTTING DOWN...
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo            Terminating service stream...
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo            Done! Thank you for using this program!
TIMEOUT /t 2 /nobreak > nul





::(%xx%) -1  I/O Stream= "SHELL.dll" 
:: IF EXIST [&1[Parser_2009]] exit

Exit
```

Comment: You are wasting too much time asking questions and you post the wrong script, it's the encoder. A simple **echo !var!** in your decode loop explains all.

Comment: im sorry but i dont understand what you mean by "a simple echo !var! in your decode loop exaplains all" and what do you mean by im wasting time asking questions? you mean in the script or in my post

Comment: in the script, i ask questions that are important, i made it to ask question , so that its user friendly not just, get the job done and close...

Answer (score 0):

> I get:
>
> t 1h a i 1d 1i
>
> Because when the program decodes the
>   letter r (which is 18) it mistakes the
>   8 in 18 for the letter h and therefore
>   puts 1h... so is there a way to make
>   it a specific search and replace?
>   (similar to if your typing a path to a
>   file with spaces in it,you would put
>   quotes around the path and file name)
>   If so what would the format be?

Aha, you got the problem. And you see the cause. 
The 18 is replaced by the line

```
set var1=!var1:8 =h !
```

**before** the correct line can replace it

```
set var1=!var1:18 =r !
```

If you can't solve the problem, then there's no room for hope. :-)

Comment: well its quite obvious that i cant solve the problem (or i wouldnt be asking the question...), thats why you guys are responding to this answer, to give feedback and/or opinions on what i should do...

Comment: your stating the obvious, what i need is the answer

Comment: You have the answer! If it fails when "set X" is BEFORE "set Y", what do you can do?

Comment: Well, it's a bit veiled and not everyone might jump to the conclusion immediately. So here it is in plain text: Replace the longer strings before the shorter ones. I.e. reverse your entire string replacement order and go from 27 to 1.